# CSS transition makes background-image bigger in Google Chrome

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to change background-image using :hover. But I get unnecessary effect. The image grows when it's hovered.

```css
.icon {
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
  transition: all 2s ease;
  background: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 16 596.1 881.4' id='logo_kamaz'%3E%3Cpath d='m177.1 21.4c-3 3-5.9 5.2-6.6 5-1.2-.5-5.5 6.9-5.5 9.5 0 1.3-2.7 5.8-4.7 7.9-.7.7-1.3 2.1-1.3 3 0 1.8-4.5 7.7-10 13.2-9.5 9.3-29.2 22.3-32.7 21.4-2.7-.7-3.6 1.9-2.3 6.4 1 3.7.2 13.2-1.1 13.2-.5 0-.9.8-.9 1.8 0 1.1-1 2.7-2.1 3.8-1.2 1-3.2 3.5-4.4 5.4-2.7 4.3-12.1 14-15.8 16.5-1.5.9-2.7 2.2-2.7 2.9 0 .6 1.9 2.7 4.2 4.7 3.9 3.4 4.2 4 4.6 9.6.5 6.8-.8 10.2-5.9 15.2-1.8 1.9-3.5 4.9-4.1 7.3-.5 2.3-1.7 21.3-2.8 42.2-1.9 38.5-2.2 40.8-6.6 51.4-.8 1.8-1.4 4.2-1.4 5.3 0 1.2-.6 3.5-1.3 5.2-7 16.4-8.8 30.5-8.9 68.7 0 34.9 3 53.7 10.4 64.6 1.3 1.9 2.7 3.4 3.1 3.4s4.9 4.2 10 9.3 12.2 11.6 15.8 14.5 7.6 7 8.7 9.1c2.6 4.6 6.9 18 7.7 24.3.5 4 1.3 5.4 5.4 9 2.6 2.4 6.8 5.6 9.2 7.3 2.4 1.6 4.6 3.2 4.9 3.5 1.1 1.2 10.1 7 10.9 7 2.6 0 12.4 12 17.5 21.5 1.5 2.7 3.5 6.2 4.4 7.6.9 1.5 2.8 4.6 4.2 6.9 2.4 4 3.9 4.9 26.7 16.2 22.5 11 29.3 15.3 29.3 18.5 0 2.2 10.5 12 15.2 14.2 6.2 2.8 14.9 2.8 20.6.1 4.5-2.2 13.8-12.6 14.8-16.6 1.2-4.7-3.2-17.4-6.1-17.4-.8 0-1.8-.6-2.2-1.4-1.5-2.6-8.5-6.5-12.9-7.2-2.4-.3-4.7-1-5-1.5s-1.4-.9-2.6-.9c-1.7 0-1.9.4-1.3 2.2.4 1.3.8 3.9.9 5.8.1 2.6-.3 3.5-1.7 3.8-4.4.9-6.7-.8-11.2-8.5-2.5-4.3-4.5-8.4-4.5-9.2 0-1.8-3.9-9.9-5.1-10.7-.5-.3-.9-1.3-.9-2.3s-.7-2.4-1.5-3.1-1.5-1.9-1.5-2.6c0-2.7-7.6-8.7-16.5-12.9-8.1-3.9-9.4-4.8-12.7-10-3.3-5-3.6-6.1-2.9-9.3.7-3.5.9-3.7 4.7-3.5 2.1.1 5.3.9 6.9 1.7 1.7.9 3.6 1.6 4.3 1.6s3.7 1.1 6.5 2.4c5.7 2.6 8.1 3.2 17.7 4.7 3.6.6 7.7 1.7 9.2 2.5 1.4.7 3.1 1.4 3.8 1.4 2 0 8.9 6.2 13.2 11.9 2.3 3.1 4.8 6.2 5.5 6.9s1.3 1.7 1.3 2.1c0 .5 3.1 2.8 7 5.2 5 3.1 8.4 6.3 12 11.1 2.7 3.7 5 6.9 5 7.2 0 1.8 9.2 13.4 12.5 15.8 7.2 5 8.4 6.5 12 14.1 1.9 4.2 3.5 7.9 3.5 8.2 0 .6 3.5 8.6 6.4 14.5 1.2 2.4 1.5 2.5 11.1 2.5 8.9-.1 10.6-.4 15.2-2.8 2.9-1.5 5.7-2.7 6.2-2.7s1.8 1.5 2.9 3.4c3.7 6.3 14.8 9.2 24.6 6.5 3.3-.9 4.1-.8 5.6.8 1.8 1.9 5.5 14.6 4.7 16-.3.4-.1 1.8.4 3 .8 2.3 1.1 2.3 17.7 2.3h16.8l5.3-5.4c3-3 6.7-6 8.3-6.7 1.9-.8 2.8-1.9 2.8-3.3 0-2.5-5.5-11.6-7-11.6-.5 0-1-.6-1-1.3-.1-.6-1.4-3-3-5.2-5.1-7-12-18.5-12-20 0-.8-.6-1.8-1.3-2.2-1.6-.9-3.7-6.6-3.7-9.9 0-1.3-.6-2.7-1.4-3.1-1.7-1-8-9.2-10-13.2-.9-1.6-3.7-6-6.2-9.6-4.4-6.3-4.7-7.2-5.5-15.8-.5-5.1-1.5-10.8-2.3-12.7-2.5-6.5-4.6-13.8-4.6-15.7 0-1.1-.7-2.8-1.5-3.9-.8-1-1.5-2.9-1.5-4.2 0-1.4-.9-2.6-2.4-3.1-2.8-1.1-7.5-7.4-11.2-15-4.1-8.4-4.3-9-5.5-17.1-2.7-19-5.5-33-6.8-34.3-.6-.6-1.1-2.3-1.1-3.7s-.7-3.5-1.5-4.6c-.8-1-1.5-2.8-1.5-4 0-1.1-.7-2.9-1.5-4-.8-1-1.5-2.9-1.5-4.2 0-2-3.5-9.8-5.1-11.2-1-1-4.9-9.1-4.9-10.3 0-.7-.5-1.8-1.1-2.4-.7-.7-1.3-6.3-1.5-14.5-.3-14.1-2.6-41-4.3-49.3-.6-2.8-1.8-9.3-2.6-14.5-1.2-6.8-2.6-11.3-5.1-15.8-2-3.8-3.4-7.7-3.4-9.8 0-3.2.4-3.7 4.6-5.6 3.4-1.5 5.9-1.9 9.3-1.5 16.9 2 23.5 2.9 30.1 4.4 5.9 1.4 12 1.8 29 1.7 19.4 0 22-.2 27-2.1 6.3-2.5 7-3.5 3.5-5.1-6.6-3 .5-9.8 13-12.5 4.4-1 9.8-2.2 12-2.8s5.6-1.4 7.5-1.9c9.6-2.4 16.7-6.6 15.7-9.4-.4-1-1.8-1.6-3.7-1.6-2.2 0-3-.5-3-1.8 0-2.4 3-5.2 5.6-5.2 1-.1 3-.7 4.4-1.5s3.7-1.4 5.2-1.5c1.5 0 2.9-.4 3.2-.9s2-1.2 3.8-1.5c3.7-.8 7.7-3.8 10.3-7.9 2.5-3.9 1-5.2-4.1-3.7-3 .9-14.1.8-46.9-.3-47-1.5-72.8-1.4-90.5.2-13.7 1.3-33.1 5.1-39.2 7.7-8.9 3.9-26.5 12.7-31 15.6-5.4 3.4-7.3 3.4-23.8.3-7.8-1.4-11.9-1.6-23-1-20 1.1-20.1 1.1-22.1-1.4-1.1-1.3-1.6-2.8-1.1-3.5.4-.6.7-15.7.7-33.6 0-40.5-.6-38.4 12.3-39.3 9.3-.7 19.9-3 21.6-4.7.5-.5 1.8-1 2.7-1s3.5-1.9 5.8-4.3c4-4.2 4.6-4.4 12.9-5.5 14.5-1.9 25.5-2.1 27.7-.6 2.4 1.8 8.9 1.8 12.3 0 3.7-1.9 6.7-5.5 8.1-9.5 2.2-6.8 2.2-6.8-8.8-6.3-14.2.7-19.3-1.4-17.2-7.1 2-5.2 3.2-5.5 23.5-7.6 8.7-.9 10.3-1.4 12.8-3.8 3.9-3.7 4-8.9.1-10.3-1.6-.6-4.1-1.7-5.7-2.6-2.1-1.2-3.9-1.4-7-.9-12.6 2.4-19.3.2-18-5.9 1.1-5.4 2.5-6.1 8.3-4.2 7.4 2.4 9.1 2.2 9.1-1.3 0-3-2-5.3-4.8-5.7-1-.1-4.6-.7-8.2-1.3-4.1-.7-16-.8-32.2-.4-23.6.6-26.7.4-36.5-1.5-6-1.1-14.8-2.6-19.8-3.2-12.5-1.6-15.5-3.9-12.1-9.3.8-1.2 1.7-3.2 2.1-4.4.5-1.9.3-2.2-1.2-1.6-1 .3-2.5 1.2-3.3 1.8-1.5 1.3-15.4 4.5-19.4 4.5-1.2 0-3-.6-4-1.3-1.5-1.1-1.6-2.1-.6-9.9 1-8 .7-11.8-.9-11.8-.4 0-3.1 2.4-6 5.4zm64.5 37.8c1.6 1.2 3.1 2.3 3.2 2.4.2.1.7 1.8 1.2 3.8.6 2.9.4 3.8-1.4 5.5-3.2 3-8.9 3.6-14.1 1.6-7.4-2.8-8.7-6.2-4.1-11.4 4.1-4.6 10.6-5.4 15.2-1.9zm-33.2 78.8c1.7 1.7 1.8 2.6.7 16.1-.7 7.9-1.6 20.2-2.2 27.4-.6 7.1-.9 25-.6 39.7.3 25.6.3 26.8-1.5 27.4-3.3 1-5.5-2.1-6.1-8.9-.6-6.4-1.8-12.2-4.5-21.6-1.2-4.4-1.5-11.4-1.4-36.5.1-46.1.6-48.5 9.4-46.4 2.3.6 5.1 1.9 6.2 2.8zm32.5 87.5c5.2.8 9.9 1.9 10.4 2.4.6.6 1.9 1.1 2.8 1.1 1 0 5.2 1.5 9.3 3.4 6.8 3.1 7.7 3.3 9.1 2 .8-.9 1.5-3.1 1.5-5 0-5.1 1.2-4.9 18 2.9 3.6 1.7 9.1 5.2 12.3 7.8 6.9 5.7 15.9 16.5 17.7 21.1.6 1.8 1.8 4.9 2.6 6.8 1.9 4.9 3.4 15.2 3.4 23.5-.1 6.2-.7 10.9-3.9 27.5-.5 2.5-1.9 7-3.1 10s-2.3 7-2.5 8.8c-.2 4.3-3.7 7.8-9.9 9.9-5.5 1.9-5.9 2-9.3 2.2-3.9.2-4.1 7.1-.2 7.1 3.2 0 8.7 2.7 11.5 5.7 8.2 8.7 11.5 18.1 7.7 21.9-2.5 2.5-7.7 4.4-11.9 4.4-3.3 0-4.4-.7-9.3-6.1-8.4-9.2-11.2-10.2-20-7.3-3.6 1.1-5.4 1.3-7.5.4-2.6-1-2.8-1.4-2.3-4.8.7-4.3 6.6-10.2 10.3-10.2 1.2 0 2.9-1.1 3.9-2.6 1.6-2.5 1.6-2.9.1-6.1-.9-1.8-1.6-3.8-1.6-4.3s-2.2-4.2-5-8.2c-2.7-4-5-7.7-5-8.3s-1.2-2.4-2.7-4.1c-1.6-1.6-3.7-4.3-4.7-5.9-2.2-3.3-4.5-6.2-20.9-25-6.2-7.2-11.7-13.7-12.2-14.5-.6-.8-1.3-4.2-1.7-7.5s-1.2-9.2-1.7-13c-1.8-12.8-3.2-31.8-2.5-33.9 1.3-4.1 3-4.3 17.3-2.1zm1.3 101.3c.7.7 1.9 1.2 2.8 1.2 4 0 15 16.2 15 22 0 3.4-1.9 9-3.1 9-.5 0-.9.9-.9 2.1 0 2.9-4.6 8.5-9 11-3.4 1.9-3.9 2.7-5 8.3-1.3 6.8-2.8 9-8.2 11.7-6.7 3.4-15.8 1.8-15.8-2.8 0-4.5 2.8-9.8 7.3-13.5 2.6-2.2 4.7-4.6 4.7-5.4s.5-2.3 1.2-3.3c.9-1.5.7-2.5-1.1-5.5-1.3-2-2.8-3.5-3.4-3.4-.7.1-4.7-2.3-8.9-5.5-6.2-4.6-7.9-6.4-8.7-9.5-1.9-6.7-1.4-11.7 1.6-15.2l2.7-3.2 13.8.4c8.7.3 14.3.9 15 1.6zm-99.9 31.1c8.3 5.6 23.6 19.6 25.6 23.5 2.1 3.8 6.7 6.3 13.1 6.9 6 .5 15.7 3.4 16.6 4.8.3.5 2.4.9 4.8.9 5.6 0 7.9 2.4 7.4 7.6-.3 3.5-.8 4.1-6.2 7.2-7.4 4.3-12.2 4.9-23.4 2.9-4.8-.9-13.5-2-19.4-2.5-9.5-.8-11.5-1.3-19.5-5.1-18.1-8.7-21.4-13.4-22.9-32.8-.6-7-.5-7.3 2.2-9.9 2.9-2.6 12.2-8.4 13.7-8.4.4 0 4 2.2 8 4.9zm195.6 55.9c7.8 5.1 10.9 10.2 16.2 27.2 1.1 3.6 2.7 7.8 3.6 9.5.8 1.6 3.6 7 6.1 12 2.6 4.9 6.5 12.3 8.9 16.3s4.3 7.6 4.3 8 2 3.7 4.4 7.3c3.5 5.5 4.4 7.7 4.9 12.8.5 5.7.3 6.3-1.9 7.7-4.9 3.3-13.8 1.5-17-3.4-1.5-2.2-1.7-4.8-1.7-14.5.2-11.5.1-11.8-2.5-14.4-1.5-1.5-3.1-3.5-3.7-4.4-5.8-10-8.3-13.4-13.7-18.6-3.5-3.3-8.3-7-10.6-8.2-8-4.1-17.3-22.7-15.9-31.7.3-2 1.3-4.7 2.3-6.1 1.5-2.4 1.9-2.5 7.6-1.9 3.4.4 7.2 1.5 8.7 2.4zm-42.9 16.4c5.7 10.8 11.7 18.2 18 22.1 6.9 4.1 12.2 8.6 15.7 13.3 3.9 5.1 11.4 22.2 13.9 31.9 2.4 9.3 8.5 21.1 14.5 28.1 1.5 1.8 3.5 5.4 4.5 8 1 2.7 2.4 6 3.1 7.4 1.6 3.1 1.7 7.2.1 8.8-2.4 2.4-6.2 1.1-17.7-5.8-15.2-9.2-15.1-9.2-16.2-14.1-1-4.4-6.1-10.1-18.2-20.4-5.9-4.9-9.7-10.6-9.7-14.4 0-1-.6-2.1-1.4-2.4-.7-.3-1.7-1.8-2.1-3.4-.3-1.5-1-3-1.4-3.3s-2-3-3.4-6.2c-2.9-6-8.7-11.7-18.7-18.1-3-1.9-6.8-4.8-8.4-6.5-2.5-2.7-2.7-3.5-2.1-7.4.4-2.3 1.6-6 2.7-8.1 2.6-5.1 9.6-12.7 11.7-12.7 1 0 2.6-.7 3.7-1.5 1-.8 3.3-1.5 5-1.5 2.9 0 3.5.6 6.4 6.2zm-130.6 9.7c4.8 4 11.6 16.5 14.7 26.9.6 1.9 2.1 5.4 3.5 7.9 1.3 2.5 2.4 4.9 2.4 5.3 0 2.6 8 12.3 13 16 8.8 6.3 9.2 12.8.9 15-6.5 1.8-10.1 1-11.9-2.5-.9-1.7-2.8-4.9-4.3-7.2-1.5-2.4-2.7-4.5-2.7-4.8s-1-2-2.2-3.8c-8.6-12.3-12.6-17.1-16.2-19.6-2.2-1.6-6.5-5.2-9.3-7.9-5.3-5-5.3-5.1-5.3-11.2 0-11.5 4.8-17.5 13-16.2 1.4.3 3.4 1.2 4.4 2.1zm228.8 101.3c3.8 3.1 17.3 28.3 18.3 34.1.5 3.4.2 4.2-2.8 7.2-2.7 2.7-4.3 3.5-7.1 3.5-4.3 0-5.5-1.9-5.5-8.1 0-2.4-.5-9-1.2-14.5l-1.2-10.1h-4c-5.3 0-8.5-3.4-6.4-6.7.8-1.2 1.9-3.1 2.6-4.4 1.3-2.4 4.8-2.9 7.3-1zm-393.2 142.3v11.5l297.8-.2 297.7-.3.3-9.5c.3-11.4-.2-12.3-4.8-11-2.3.7-105.5 1-293.1 1-255.2 0-290.1-.2-293.2-1.5-2-.8-3.9-1.5-4.2-1.5s-.5 5.2-.5 11.5zm126.2 75.1c-2.1.9-6.8 1.5-13 1.5-17.1.1-14.9-1.2-39.2 23.3-11.8 11.9-22.5 21.9-23.7 22.2s-3.1.3-4.3-.1c-1.9-.6-2.1-1.2-1.5-4.3.4-2.1.9-12 1.2-22.3l.4-18.5-17.8-.2c-9.8-.1-19-.4-20.4-.8-2.1-.4-2.8-.1-3.3 1.8-.3 1.3-.6 32.3-.6 69v66.8h42.5l-.3-27-.4-26.9 5.3-5.6c2.8-3 5.7-5.5 6.4-5.5 1.8 0 4 3 6.4 9 1.2 3 2.6 6.4 3.1 7.5s2.3 5.8 4 10.5c1.8 4.7 4 10.3 5 12.5s3 7.6 4.5 12 3.5 9.2 4.3 10.7l1.6 2.8 27.1.1c14.8.1 27.7 0 28.5-.1 2-.3 2.9-1.8 3.6-6.3.4-2.1 1.5-4.9 2.6-6.2l1.9-2.5h19.9c10.9 0 20.6.3 21.5.6 1.7.7 4.3 5.9 5.4 10.9l.7 3h59.6l-.1-35.2c-.1-19.8.2-35.4.7-35.7 1-.6 5.2 4.7 5.2 6.6 0 1.6 4.5 14.7 5.4 15.5.3.4.6 1.7.6 3s.6 3.6 1.4 5.1 1.8 4.6 2.1 6.7c.4 2.2 1 4.4 1.4 5 1.2 2 6.3 17.1 7.1 21.3 1.1 5.1 2.5 7.8 4.2 8.3.7.2 8.5.2 17.3-.1l15.9-.5 1.8-5c1.8-4.8 2.2-6.3 4.8-16.5.7-2.5 1.8-5.9 2.6-7.7.8-1.7 1.4-3.7 1.4-4.5 0-.7 2.1-7.4 4.5-14.8 2.5-7.4 4.5-14.7 4.5-16.1 0-2.7 3.5-6.8 4.7-5.5.4.4.6 16.4.4 35.7l-.3 34.9h31.6c24.5 0 31.7-.3 32-1.3 4.1-14.5 2.5-13.7 27-13.7h20.4l2 3.4c1.1 1.8 2.3 4.8 2.7 6.5s1.6 3.7 2.8 4.4c1.7.9 17.1 1.1 66.7.7l64.5-.5.3-7.1c.3-7.9-1.1-13.5-3-11.6-.8.8-7.5 1.2-21.8 1.2-17 0-20.9-.3-22.8-1.6-2.7-1.9-2.8-3.8-.3-7.2 1-1.5 2.9-5.2 4.1-8.2s3.4-8 4.7-11c1.4-3 3.4-8 4.5-11 1.9-5.3 3.5-9.3 6.3-15.5.7-1.7 2.1-5 3-7.5 2.4-6.3 3.8-9.5 7.4-17.1 1.7-3.6 3.1-7.3 3.1-8.3s.6-3 1.4-4.4c.8-1.5 2.2-4.5 3.1-6.7s2.2-5.4 3-7c4.7-10.7 5.8-13.6 5.3-14-.3-.3-4.1-.2-8.4.2-7.6.8-80.8.1-84.9-.8-1.9-.4-2 .2-2.3 9.2-.3 11.6-2.4 10.6 21.5 10.7 12.2.1 16.9.5 17.5 1.4 1 1.6.3 6.2-1.6 10.3-.8 1.6-1.9 4.1-2.4 5.5-.6 1.4-2.2 5.1-3.6 8.2s-2.6 5.9-2.6 6.2-1.7 4.3-3.9 8.8c-2.1 4.6-4.2 9.8-4.5 11.5-.4 1.8-1.2 3.5-1.7 3.8-.5.4-.9 1.4-.9 2.4s-.7 2.4-1.5 3.1-1.5 2-1.5 2.9-1.6 4.7-3.5 8.6c-1.9 3.8-3.5 7.8-3.5 8.7s-.4 1.9-.9 2.2c-.4.3-1.1 2.6-1.5 5.2-.7 5.5-2 7.4-5.1 7.4-3.2 0-4.1-1.6-5.4-8.9-.6-3.6-1.5-6.9-2.1-7.5-.5-.5-1-2.4-1-4.2 0-1.7-.7-3.7-1.5-4.4s-1.5-2.3-1.5-3.5c0-1.3-.7-3.6-1.5-5.1-.8-1.6-1.5-4.3-1.5-6.1 0-1.7-.7-3.8-1.5-4.6-.7-.8-1.7-2.6-2.1-4.1-.3-1.4-1-2.9-1.5-3.2s-.9-1.8-.9-3.3-.7-3.6-1.5-4.7c-.8-1-1.5-3.4-1.5-5.2s-.5-4.3-1.2-5.5c-1.9-3.4-4.7-12-4.8-14.3 0-1.2-.7-2.7-1.5-3.4s-1.5-2-1.5-3-.7-3.4-1.5-5.3c-.8-2-1.5-4.9-1.5-6.4-.1-1.5-1.1-4.6-2.4-6.8-2.8-4.8-4.6-5.3-21.4-5.6l-12.3-.1-2 3.6c-1 2-1.9 4.8-1.9 6.3 0 1.6-.7 4.1-1.5 5.7-.8 1.5-1.5 3.5-1.5 4.3s-.6 2.7-1.4 4.1c-.7 1.5-2.4 6.1-3.7 10.2-1.2 4.1-2.9 8.6-3.6 10s-1.3 3.5-1.3 4.8c0 1.2-.4 3-.9 4-.5.9-1.7 3.7-2.6 6.2s-2.3 6-3.1 7.8-1.4 4.4-1.4 5.7c0 2.3-1.6 6.7-4.6 12.8-.8 1.6-1.4 3.8-1.4 5s-.9 4.9-1.9 8.2c-1.4 4.5-2.4 6.1-3.9 6.3-2.6.4-4.9-3.3-3.3-5.2.8-.9 1-16.5.9-50.7-.3-41.3-.5-49.4-1.7-49.1-.7.2-11.6.3-24.1.4l-22.7.1-1.3 3.1c-.7 1.7-1.7 4.2-2.1 5.6s-2.4 7-4.4 12.5-4.3 12.4-5.1 15.3c-.7 2.8-2.1 6.9-3 9-2.8 6.8-5.1 14.6-6.4 21.7-1.5 8.8-4.6 11.7-8.4 7.9-1-1-1.6-3.3-1.6-6.4 0-2.6-.7-6.1-1.5-7.6-.8-1.6-1.5-4.3-1.5-5.9 0-1.7-.7-3.9-1.5-4.9-.8-1.1-1.5-2.8-1.5-3.9 0-1-.6-3.1-1.4-4.5-1.3-2.6-3.1-8.8-4.6-16.2-.3-1.9-1.4-5-2.4-6.8-1-1.9-1.5-3.6-1.2-3.9s0-1.5-.7-2.7c-.6-1.1-1.3-3.2-1.4-4.6-.1-1.3-1.1-3.6-2.1-5l-1.9-2.5-22.8-.2c-14.3-.2-23.2-.7-24-1.3-1-.8-1.6-.7-2.2.2-1.3 2.1-1.6 77.7-.3 91.7 1.1 10.7 1 12.5-.3 13.8-3.2 3.3-7.7-2.7-7.7-10.3 0-1.8-.4-3.6-1-3.9-.5-.3-1-1.5-1-2.7 0-1.1-.6-3.2-1.4-4.6-.8-1.5-2.2-5.9-3.1-9.7-1-3.9-2.3-7.7-3-8.5s-1.5-2.6-1.8-4-1-4-1.6-5.8c-2.6-7.7-3.3-9.9-4.1-12.7-1.3-4.8-3.1-9.8-4.6-12.8-.8-1.6-1.4-3.6-1.4-4.6 0-.9-.7-2.6-1.5-3.7-.8-1-1.5-2.8-1.5-3.8 0-4.2-4.1-15.4-5.8-16.1-.9-.4-6-.9-11.2-1.1-5.2-.3-11.8-.6-14.6-.7-4.8-.3-5.2-.2-6.7 2.7-.9 1.7-1.9 4.4-2.3 6.1-.8 3.8-3.2 11.4-4.4 14-.4 1.1-1.8 4.9-3 8.5-1.1 3.6-2.4 7.4-2.9 8.5-1.8 4.1-3 8.1-3.7 12-.3 2.2-1.2 5-2 6.2s-1.4 3.1-1.4 4.1-.7 2.7-1.5 3.8c-.8 1-1.5 2.6-1.5 3.5 0 1.7-2.2 8.7-6.5 20.4-1.3 3.8-2.8 9.2-3.1 12-.9 6.9-1.9 8.5-5.4 8.5-3.3 0-4.4-1.5-5.5-7.4-.3-2.2-1.3-4.9-2.1-6s-1.4-3-1.4-4.3c0-1.8-1.1-4.5-7.1-16.5-.5-1-.9-2.6-.9-3.6s-.7-2.7-1.5-3.8c-.8-1-1.5-2.8-1.5-3.9s-.9-3.8-2-6-1.9-4.4-2-4.8c0-.5-.7-1.5-1.5-2.3-.8-.9-1.5-2.4-1.5-3.4s-.4-2.2-1-2.5c-.5-.3-1-2.5-1-4.8 0-4.1.3-4.5 19-22.7 20.9-20.4 23.2-23.8 13.2-19.4zm48.6 68.1c1.2 3.8 2.2 7.6 2.2 8.5s.5 2 1 2.3c.6.3 1 1.4 1 2.3s1.6 5.4 3.6 9.9 3.4 8.9 3.1 9.8c-1.1 2.7-5.9 3.7-16.9 3.3-14.9-.4-14.9-.5-9.7-13.8 2.3-5.8 4.3-11.6 4.6-13s.9-3 1.3-3.5c.4-.6 1.1-2.6 1.5-4.5.9-4.3 3.1-8 4.8-8 .8 0 2.3 3 3.5 6.7zm260.2-4.6c.7 1.1 2.2 5.5 3.5 9.7 3.2 10.5 5.3 16.2 6.9 19.2.8 1.4 1.7 4.1 2.1 6.1.6 3.4.5 3.7-2.6 4.8-3.9 1.4-20.8 1.5-24.3.1-3.1-1.2-3.3-3.4-.7-9.2 1.1-2.4 2.7-7 3.7-10.3s2.1-6.5 2.5-7c.3-.6 1.6-4.3 2.9-8.3 2.4-7.4 4.1-8.8 6-5.1z' fill='%230d53a0'%3E%3C/path%3E%3C/svg%3E") no-repeat;
}

.icon:hover {
  background: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 16 596.1 881.4' id='logo_kamaz'%3E%3Cpath d='m177.1 21.4c-3 3-5.9 5.2-6.6 5-1.2-.5-5.5 6.9-5.5 9.5 0 1.3-2.7 5.8-4.7 7.9-.7.7-1.3 2.1-1.3 3 0 1.8-4.5 7.7-10 13.2-9.5 9.3-29.2 22.3-32.7 21.4-2.7-.7-3.6 1.9-2.3 6.4 1 3.7.2 13.2-1.1 13.2-.5 0-.9.8-.9 1.8 0 1.1-1 2.7-2.1 3.8-1.2 1-3.2 3.5-4.4 5.4-2.7 4.3-12.1 14-15.8 16.5-1.5.9-2.7 2.2-2.7 2.9 0 .6 1.9 2.7 4.2 4.7 3.9 3.4 4.2 4 4.6 9.6.5 6.8-.8 10.2-5.9 15.2-1.8 1.9-3.5 4.9-4.1 7.3-.5 2.3-1.7 21.3-2.8 42.2-1.9 38.5-2.2 40.8-6.6 51.4-.8 1.8-1.4 4.2-1.4 5.3 0 1.2-.6 3.5-1.3 5.2-7 16.4-8.8 30.5-8.9 68.7 0 34.9 3 53.7 10.4 64.6 1.3 1.9 2.7 3.4 3.1 3.4s4.9 4.2 10 9.3 12.2 11.6 15.8 14.5 7.6 7 8.7 9.1c2.6 4.6 6.9 18 7.7 24.3.5 4 1.3 5.4 5.4 9 2.6 2.4 6.8 5.6 9.2 7.3 2.4 1.6 4.6 3.2 4.9 3.5 1.1 1.2 10.1 7 10.9 7 2.6 0 12.4 12 17.5 21.5 1.5 2.7 3.5 6.2 4.4 7.6.9 1.5 2.8 4.6 4.2 6.9 2.4 4 3.9 4.9 26.7 16.2 22.5 11 29.3 15.3 29.3 18.5 0 2.2 10.5 12 15.2 14.2 6.2 2.8 14.9 2.8 20.6.1 4.5-2.2 13.8-12.6 14.8-16.6 1.2-4.7-3.2-17.4-6.1-17.4-.8 0-1.8-.6-2.2-1.4-1.5-2.6-8.5-6.5-12.9-7.2-2.4-.3-4.7-1-5-1.5s-1.4-.9-2.6-.9c-1.7 0-1.9.4-1.3 2.2.4 1.3.8 3.9.9 5.8.1 2.6-.3 3.5-1.7 3.8-4.4.9-6.7-.8-11.2-8.5-2.5-4.3-4.5-8.4-4.5-9.2 0-1.8-3.9-9.9-5.1-10.7-.5-.3-.9-1.3-.9-2.3s-.7-2.4-1.5-3.1-1.5-1.9-1.5-2.6c0-2.7-7.6-8.7-16.5-12.9-8.1-3.9-9.4-4.8-12.7-10-3.3-5-3.6-6.1-2.9-9.3.7-3.5.9-3.7 4.7-3.5 2.1.1 5.3.9 6.9 1.7 1.7.9 3.6 1.6 4.3 1.6s3.7 1.1 6.5 2.4c5.7 2.6 8.1 3.2 17.7 4.7 3.6.6 7.7 1.7 9.2 2.5 1.4.7 3.1 1.4 3.8 1.4 2 0 8.9 6.2 13.2 11.9 2.3 3.1 4.8 6.2 5.5 6.9s1.3 1.7 1.3 2.1c0 .5 3.1 2.8 7 5.2 5 3.1 8.4 6.3 12 11.1 2.7 3.7 5 6.9 5 7.2 0 1.8 9.2 13.4 12.5 15.8 7.2 5 8.4 6.5 12 14.1 1.9 4.2 3.5 7.9 3.5 8.2 0 .6 3.5 8.6 6.4 14.5 1.2 2.4 1.5 2.5 11.1 2.5 8.9-.1 10.6-.4 15.2-2.8 2.9-1.5 5.7-2.7 6.2-2.7s1.8 1.5 2.9 3.4c3.7 6.3 14.8 9.2 24.6 6.5 3.3-.9 4.1-.8 5.6.8 1.8 1.9 5.5 14.6 4.7 16-.3.4-.1 1.8.4 3 .8 2.3 1.1 2.3 17.7 2.3h16.8l5.3-5.4c3-3 6.7-6 8.3-6.7 1.9-.8 2.8-1.9 2.8-3.3 0-2.5-5.5-11.6-7-11.6-.5 0-1-.6-1-1.3-.1-.6-1.4-3-3-5.2-5.1-7-12-18.5-12-20 0-.8-.6-1.8-1.3-2.2-1.6-.9-3.7-6.6-3.7-9.9 0-1.3-.6-2.7-1.4-3.1-1.7-1-8-9.2-10-13.2-.9-1.6-3.7-6-6.2-9.6-4.4-6.3-4.7-7.2-5.5-15.8-.5-5.1-1.5-10.8-2.3-12.7-2.5-6.5-4.6-13.8-4.6-15.7 0-1.1-.7-2.8-1.5-3.9-.8-1-1.5-2.9-1.5-4.2 0-1.4-.9-2.6-2.4-3.1-2.8-1.1-7.5-7.4-11.2-15-4.1-8.4-4.3-9-5.5-17.1-2.7-19-5.5-33-6.8-34.3-.6-.6-1.1-2.3-1.1-3.7s-.7-3.5-1.5-4.6c-.8-1-1.5-2.8-1.5-4 0-1.1-.7-2.9-1.5-4-.8-1-1.5-2.9-1.5-4.2 0-2-3.5-9.8-5.1-11.2-1-1-4.9-9.1-4.9-10.3 0-.7-.5-1.8-1.1-2.4-.7-.7-1.3-6.3-1.5-14.5-.3-14.1-2.6-41-4.3-49.3-.6-2.8-1.8-9.3-2.6-14.5-1.2-6.8-2.6-11.3-5.1-15.8-2-3.8-3.4-7.7-3.4-9.8 0-3.2.4-3.7 4.6-5.6 3.4-1.5 5.9-1.9 9.3-1.5 16.9 2 23.5 2.9 30.1 4.4 5.9 1.4 12 1.8 29 1.7 19.4 0 22-.2 27-2.1 6.3-2.5 7-3.5 3.5-5.1-6.6-3 .5-9.8 13-12.5 4.4-1 9.8-2.2 12-2.8s5.6-1.4 7.5-1.9c9.6-2.4 16.7-6.6 15.7-9.4-.4-1-1.8-1.6-3.7-1.6-2.2 0-3-.5-3-1.8 0-2.4 3-5.2 5.6-5.2 1-.1 3-.7 4.4-1.5s3.7-1.4 5.2-1.5c1.5 0 2.9-.4 3.2-.9s2-1.2 3.8-1.5c3.7-.8 7.7-3.8 10.3-7.9 2.5-3.9 1-5.2-4.1-3.7-3 .9-14.1.8-46.9-.3-47-1.5-72.8-1.4-90.5.2-13.7 1.3-33.1 5.1-39.2 7.7-8.9 3.9-26.5 12.7-31 15.6-5.4 3.4-7.3 3.4-23.8.3-7.8-1.4-11.9-1.6-23-1-20 1.1-20.1 1.1-22.1-1.4-1.1-1.3-1.6-2.8-1.1-3.5.4-.6.7-15.7.7-33.6 0-40.5-.6-38.4 12.3-39.3 9.3-.7 19.9-3 21.6-4.7.5-.5 1.8-1 2.7-1s3.5-1.9 5.8-4.3c4-4.2 4.6-4.4 12.9-5.5 14.5-1.9 25.5-2.1 27.7-.6 2.4 1.8 8.9 1.8 12.3 0 3.7-1.9 6.7-5.5 8.1-9.5 2.2-6.8 2.2-6.8-8.8-6.3-14.2.7-19.3-1.4-17.2-7.1 2-5.2 3.2-5.5 23.5-7.6 8.7-.9 10.3-1.4 12.8-3.8 3.9-3.7 4-8.9.1-10.3-1.6-.6-4.1-1.7-5.7-2.6-2.1-1.2-3.9-1.4-7-.9-12.6 2.4-19.3.2-18-5.9 1.1-5.4 2.5-6.1 8.3-4.2 7.4 2.4 9.1 2.2 9.1-1.3 0-3-2-5.3-4.8-5.7-1-.1-4.6-.7-8.2-1.3-4.1-.7-16-.8-32.2-.4-23.6.6-26.7.4-36.5-1.5-6-1.1-14.8-2.6-19.8-3.2-12.5-1.6-15.5-3.9-12.1-9.3.8-1.2 1.7-3.2 2.1-4.4.5-1.9.3-2.2-1.2-1.6-1 .3-2.5 1.2-3.3 1.8-1.5 1.3-15.4 4.5-19.4 4.5-1.2 0-3-.6-4-1.3-1.5-1.1-1.6-2.1-.6-9.9 1-8 .7-11.8-.9-11.8-.4 0-3.1 2.4-6 5.4zm64.5 37.8c1.6 1.2 3.1 2.3 3.2 2.4.2.1.7 1.8 1.2 3.8.6 2.9.4 3.8-1.4 5.5-3.2 3-8.9 3.6-14.1 1.6-7.4-2.8-8.7-6.2-4.1-11.4 4.1-4.6 10.6-5.4 15.2-1.9zm-33.2 78.8c1.7 1.7 1.8 2.6.7 16.1-.7 7.9-1.6 20.2-2.2 27.4-.6 7.1-.9 25-.6 39.7.3 25.6.3 26.8-1.5 27.4-3.3 1-5.5-2.1-6.1-8.9-.6-6.4-1.8-12.2-4.5-21.6-1.2-4.4-1.5-11.4-1.4-36.5.1-46.1.6-48.5 9.4-46.4 2.3.6 5.1 1.9 6.2 2.8zm32.5 87.5c5.2.8 9.9 1.9 10.4 2.4.6.6 1.9 1.1 2.8 1.1 1 0 5.2 1.5 9.3 3.4 6.8 3.1 7.7 3.3 9.1 2 .8-.9 1.5-3.1 1.5-5 0-5.1 1.2-4.9 18 2.9 3.6 1.7 9.1 5.2 12.3 7.8 6.9 5.7 15.9 16.5 17.7 21.1.6 1.8 1.8 4.9 2.6 6.8 1.9 4.9 3.4 15.2 3.4 23.5-.1 6.2-.7 10.9-3.9 27.5-.5 2.5-1.9 7-3.1 10s-2.3 7-2.5 8.8c-.2 4.3-3.7 7.8-9.9 9.9-5.5 1.9-5.9 2-9.3 2.2-3.9.2-4.1 7.1-.2 7.1 3.2 0 8.7 2.7 11.5 5.7 8.2 8.7 11.5 18.1 7.7 21.9-2.5 2.5-7.7 4.4-11.9 4.4-3.3 0-4.4-.7-9.3-6.1-8.4-9.2-11.2-10.2-20-7.3-3.6 1.1-5.4 1.3-7.5.4-2.6-1-2.8-1.4-2.3-4.8.7-4.3 6.6-10.2 10.3-10.2 1.2 0 2.9-1.1 3.9-2.6 1.6-2.5 1.6-2.9.1-6.1-.9-1.8-1.6-3.8-1.6-4.3s-2.2-4.2-5-8.2c-2.7-4-5-7.7-5-8.3s-1.2-2.4-2.7-4.1c-1.6-1.6-3.7-4.3-4.7-5.9-2.2-3.3-4.5-6.2-20.9-25-6.2-7.2-11.7-13.7-12.2-14.5-.6-.8-1.3-4.2-1.7-7.5s-1.2-9.2-1.7-13c-1.8-12.8-3.2-31.8-2.5-33.9 1.3-4.1 3-4.3 17.3-2.1zm1.3 101.3c.7.7 1.9 1.2 2.8 1.2 4 0 15 16.2 15 22 0 3.4-1.9 9-3.1 9-.5 0-.9.9-.9 2.1 0 2.9-4.6 8.5-9 11-3.4 1.9-3.9 2.7-5 8.3-1.3 6.8-2.8 9-8.2 11.7-6.7 3.4-15.8 1.8-15.8-2.8 0-4.5 2.8-9.8 7.3-13.5 2.6-2.2 4.7-4.6 4.7-5.4s.5-2.3 1.2-3.3c.9-1.5.7-2.5-1.1-5.5-1.3-2-2.8-3.5-3.4-3.4-.7.1-4.7-2.3-8.9-5.5-6.2-4.6-7.9-6.4-8.7-9.5-1.9-6.7-1.4-11.7 1.6-15.2l2.7-3.2 13.8.4c8.7.3 14.3.9 15 1.6zm-99.9 31.1c8.3 5.6 23.6 19.6 25.6 23.5 2.1 3.8 6.7 6.3 13.1 6.9 6 .5 15.7 3.4 16.6 4.8.3.5 2.4.9 4.8.9 5.6 0 7.9 2.4 7.4 7.6-.3 3.5-.8 4.1-6.2 7.2-7.4 4.3-12.2 4.9-23.4 2.9-4.8-.9-13.5-2-19.4-2.5-9.5-.8-11.5-1.3-19.5-5.1-18.1-8.7-21.4-13.4-22.9-32.8-.6-7-.5-7.3 2.2-9.9 2.9-2.6 12.2-8.4 13.7-8.4.4 0 4 2.2 8 4.9zm195.6 55.9c7.8 5.1 10.9 10.2 16.2 27.2 1.1 3.6 2.7 7.8 3.6 9.5.8 1.6 3.6 7 6.1 12 2.6 4.9 6.5 12.3 8.9 16.3s4.3 7.6 4.3 8 2 3.7 4.4 7.3c3.5 5.5 4.4 7.7 4.9 12.8.5 5.7.3 6.3-1.9 7.7-4.9 3.3-13.8 1.5-17-3.4-1.5-2.2-1.7-4.8-1.7-14.5.2-11.5.1-11.8-2.5-14.4-1.5-1.5-3.1-3.5-3.7-4.4-5.8-10-8.3-13.4-13.7-18.6-3.5-3.3-8.3-7-10.6-8.2-8-4.1-17.3-22.7-15.9-31.7.3-2 1.3-4.7 2.3-6.1 1.5-2.4 1.9-2.5 7.6-1.9 3.4.4 7.2 1.5 8.7 2.4zm-42.9 16.4c5.7 10.8 11.7 18.2 18 22.1 6.9 4.1 12.2 8.6 15.7 13.3 3.9 5.1 11.4 22.2 13.9 31.9 2.4 9.3 8.5 21.1 14.5 28.1 1.5 1.8 3.5 5.4 4.5 8 1 2.7 2.4 6 3.1 7.4 1.6 3.1 1.7 7.2.1 8.8-2.4 2.4-6.2 1.1-17.7-5.8-15.2-9.2-15.1-9.2-16.2-14.1-1-4.4-6.1-10.1-18.2-20.4-5.9-4.9-9.7-10.6-9.7-14.4 0-1-.6-2.1-1.4-2.4-.7-.3-1.7-1.8-2.1-3.4-.3-1.5-1-3-1.4-3.3s-2-3-3.4-6.2c-2.9-6-8.7-11.7-18.7-18.1-3-1.9-6.8-4.8-8.4-6.5-2.5-2.7-2.7-3.5-2.1-7.4.4-2.3 1.6-6 2.7-8.1 2.6-5.1 9.6-12.7 11.7-12.7 1 0 2.6-.7 3.7-1.5 1-.8 3.3-1.5 5-1.5 2.9 0 3.5.6 6.4 6.2zm-130.6 9.7c4.8 4 11.6 16.5 14.7 26.9.6 1.9 2.1 5.4 3.5 7.9 1.3 2.5 2.4 4.9 2.4 5.3 0 2.6 8 12.3 13 16 8.8 6.3 9.2 12.8.9 15-6.5 1.8-10.1 1-11.9-2.5-.9-1.7-2.8-4.9-4.3-7.2-1.5-2.4-2.7-4.5-2.7-4.8s-1-2-2.2-3.8c-8.6-12.3-12.6-17.1-16.2-19.6-2.2-1.6-6.5-5.2-9.3-7.9-5.3-5-5.3-5.1-5.3-11.2 0-11.5 4.8-17.5 13-16.2 1.4.3 3.4 1.2 4.4 2.1zm228.8 101.3c3.8 3.1 17.3 28.3 18.3 34.1.5 3.4.2 4.2-2.8 7.2-2.7 2.7-4.3 3.5-7.1 3.5-4.3 0-5.5-1.9-5.5-8.1 0-2.4-.5-9-1.2-14.5l-1.2-10.1h-4c-5.3 0-8.5-3.4-6.4-6.7.8-1.2 1.9-3.1 2.6-4.4 1.3-2.4 4.8-2.9 7.3-1zm-393.2 142.3v11.5l297.8-.2 297.7-.3.3-9.5c.3-11.4-.2-12.3-4.8-11-2.3.7-105.5 1-293.1 1-255.2 0-290.1-.2-293.2-1.5-2-.8-3.9-1.5-4.2-1.5s-.5 5.2-.5 11.5zm126.2 75.1c-2.1.9-6.8 1.5-13 1.5-17.1.1-14.9-1.2-39.2 23.3-11.8 11.9-22.5 21.9-23.7 22.2s-3.1.3-4.3-.1c-1.9-.6-2.1-1.2-1.5-4.3.4-2.1.9-12 1.2-22.3l.4-18.5-17.8-.2c-9.8-.1-19-.4-20.4-.8-2.1-.4-2.8-.1-3.3 1.8-.3 1.3-.6 32.3-.6 69v66.8h42.5l-.3-27-.4-26.9 5.3-5.6c2.8-3 5.7-5.5 6.4-5.5 1.8 0 4 3 6.4 9 1.2 3 2.6 6.4 3.1 7.5s2.3 5.8 4 10.5c1.8 4.7 4 10.3 5 12.5s3 7.6 4.5 12 3.5 9.2 4.3 10.7l1.6 2.8 27.1.1c14.8.1 27.7 0 28.5-.1 2-.3 2.9-1.8 3.6-6.3.4-2.1 1.5-4.9 2.6-6.2l1.9-2.5h19.9c10.9 0 20.6.3 21.5.6 1.7.7 4.3 5.9 5.4 10.9l.7 3h59.6l-.1-35.2c-.1-19.8.2-35.4.7-35.7 1-.6 5.2 4.7 5.2 6.6 0 1.6 4.5 14.7 5.4 15.5.3.4.6 1.7.6 3s.6 3.6 1.4 5.1 1.8 4.6 2.1 6.7c.4 2.2 1 4.4 1.4 5 1.2 2 6.3 17.1 7.1 21.3 1.1 5.1 2.5 7.8 4.2 8.3.7.2 8.5.2 17.3-.1l15.9-.5 1.8-5c1.8-4.8 2.2-6.3 4.8-16.5.7-2.5 1.8-5.9 2.6-7.7.8-1.7 1.4-3.7 1.4-4.5 0-.7 2.1-7.4 4.5-14.8 2.5-7.4 4.5-14.7 4.5-16.1 0-2.7 3.5-6.8 4.7-5.5.4.4.6 16.4.4 35.7l-.3 34.9h31.6c24.5 0 31.7-.3 32-1.3 4.1-14.5 2.5-13.7 27-13.7h20.4l2 3.4c1.1 1.8 2.3 4.8 2.7 6.5s1.6 3.7 2.8 4.4c1.7.9 17.1 1.1 66.7.7l64.5-.5.3-7.1c.3-7.9-1.1-13.5-3-11.6-.8.8-7.5 1.2-21.8 1.2-17 0-20.9-.3-22.8-1.6-2.7-1.9-2.8-3.8-.3-7.2 1-1.5 2.9-5.2 4.1-8.2s3.4-8 4.7-11c1.4-3 3.4-8 4.5-11 1.9-5.3 3.5-9.3 6.3-15.5.7-1.7 2.1-5 3-7.5 2.4-6.3 3.8-9.5 7.4-17.1 1.7-3.6 3.1-7.3 3.1-8.3s.6-3 1.4-4.4c.8-1.5 2.2-4.5 3.1-6.7s2.2-5.4 3-7c4.7-10.7 5.8-13.6 5.3-14-.3-.3-4.1-.2-8.4.2-7.6.8-80.8.1-84.9-.8-1.9-.4-2 .2-2.3 9.2-.3 11.6-2.4 10.6 21.5 10.7 12.2.1 16.9.5 17.5 1.4 1 1.6.3 6.2-1.6 10.3-.8 1.6-1.9 4.1-2.4 5.5-.6 1.4-2.2 5.1-3.6 8.2s-2.6 5.9-2.6 6.2-1.7 4.3-3.9 8.8c-2.1 4.6-4.2 9.8-4.5 11.5-.4 1.8-1.2 3.5-1.7 3.8-.5.4-.9 1.4-.9 2.4s-.7 2.4-1.5 3.1-1.5 2-1.5 2.9-1.6 4.7-3.5 8.6c-1.9 3.8-3.5 7.8-3.5 8.7s-.4 1.9-.9 2.2c-.4.3-1.1 2.6-1.5 5.2-.7 5.5-2 7.4-5.1 7.4-3.2 0-4.1-1.6-5.4-8.9-.6-3.6-1.5-6.9-2.1-7.5-.5-.5-1-2.4-1-4.2 0-1.7-.7-3.7-1.5-4.4s-1.5-2.3-1.5-3.5c0-1.3-.7-3.6-1.5-5.1-.8-1.6-1.5-4.3-1.5-6.1 0-1.7-.7-3.8-1.5-4.6-.7-.8-1.7-2.6-2.1-4.1-.3-1.4-1-2.9-1.5-3.2s-.9-1.8-.9-3.3-.7-3.6-1.5-4.7c-.8-1-1.5-3.4-1.5-5.2s-.5-4.3-1.2-5.5c-1.9-3.4-4.7-12-4.8-14.3 0-1.2-.7-2.7-1.5-3.4s-1.5-2-1.5-3-.7-3.4-1.5-5.3c-.8-2-1.5-4.9-1.5-6.4-.1-1.5-1.1-4.6-2.4-6.8-2.8-4.8-4.6-5.3-21.4-5.6l-12.3-.1-2 3.6c-1 2-1.9 4.8-1.9 6.3 0 1.6-.7 4.1-1.5 5.7-.8 1.5-1.5 3.5-1.5 4.3s-.6 2.7-1.4 4.1c-.7 1.5-2.4 6.1-3.7 10.2-1.2 4.1-2.9 8.6-3.6 10s-1.3 3.5-1.3 4.8c0 1.2-.4 3-.9 4-.5.9-1.7 3.7-2.6 6.2s-2.3 6-3.1 7.8-1.4 4.4-1.4 5.7c0 2.3-1.6 6.7-4.6 12.8-.8 1.6-1.4 3.8-1.4 5s-.9 4.9-1.9 8.2c-1.4 4.5-2.4 6.1-3.9 6.3-2.6.4-4.9-3.3-3.3-5.2.8-.9 1-16.5.9-50.7-.3-41.3-.5-49.4-1.7-49.1-.7.2-11.6.3-24.1.4l-22.7.1-1.3 3.1c-.7 1.7-1.7 4.2-2.1 5.6s-2.4 7-4.4 12.5-4.3 12.4-5.1 15.3c-.7 2.8-2.1 6.9-3 9-2.8 6.8-5.1 14.6-6.4 21.7-1.5 8.8-4.6 11.7-8.4 7.9-1-1-1.6-3.3-1.6-6.4 0-2.6-.7-6.1-1.5-7.6-.8-1.6-1.5-4.3-1.5-5.9 0-1.7-.7-3.9-1.5-4.9-.8-1.1-1.5-2.8-1.5-3.9 0-1-.6-3.1-1.4-4.5-1.3-2.6-3.1-8.8-4.6-16.2-.3-1.9-1.4-5-2.4-6.8-1-1.9-1.5-3.6-1.2-3.9s0-1.5-.7-2.7c-.6-1.1-1.3-3.2-1.4-4.6-.1-1.3-1.1-3.6-2.1-5l-1.9-2.5-22.8-.2c-14.3-.2-23.2-.7-24-1.3-1-.8-1.6-.7-2.2.2-1.3 2.1-1.6 77.7-.3 91.7 1.1 10.7 1 12.5-.3 13.8-3.2 3.3-7.7-2.7-7.7-10.3 0-1.8-.4-3.6-1-3.9-.5-.3-1-1.5-1-2.7 0-1.1-.6-3.2-1.4-4.6-.8-1.5-2.2-5.9-3.1-9.7-1-3.9-2.3-7.7-3-8.5s-1.5-2.6-1.8-4-1-4-1.6-5.8c-2.6-7.7-3.3-9.9-4.1-12.7-1.3-4.8-3.1-9.8-4.6-12.8-.8-1.6-1.4-3.6-1.4-4.6 0-.9-.7-2.6-1.5-3.7-.8-1-1.5-2.8-1.5-3.8 0-4.2-4.1-15.4-5.8-16.1-.9-.4-6-.9-11.2-1.1-5.2-.3-11.8-.6-14.6-.7-4.8-.3-5.2-.2-6.7 2.7-.9 1.7-1.9 4.4-2.3 6.1-.8 3.8-3.2 11.4-4.4 14-.4 1.1-1.8 4.9-3 8.5-1.1 3.6-2.4 7.4-2.9 8.5-1.8 4.1-3 8.1-3.7 12-.3 2.2-1.2 5-2 6.2s-1.4 3.1-1.4 4.1-.7 2.7-1.5 3.8c-.8 1-1.5 2.6-1.5 3.5 0 1.7-2.2 8.7-6.5 20.4-1.3 3.8-2.8 9.2-3.1 12-.9 6.9-1.9 8.5-5.4 8.5-3.3 0-4.4-1.5-5.5-7.4-.3-2.2-1.3-4.9-2.1-6s-1.4-3-1.4-4.3c0-1.8-1.1-4.5-7.1-16.5-.5-1-.9-2.6-.9-3.6s-.7-2.7-1.5-3.8c-.8-1-1.5-2.8-1.5-3.9s-.9-3.8-2-6-1.9-4.4-2-4.8c0-.5-.7-1.5-1.5-2.3-.8-.9-1.5-2.4-1.5-3.4s-.4-2.2-1-2.5c-.5-.3-1-2.5-1-4.8 0-4.1.3-4.5 19-22.7 20.9-20.4 23.2-23.8 13.2-19.4zm48.6 68.1c1.2 3.8 2.2 7.6 2.2 8.5s.5 2 1 2.3c.6.3 1 1.4 1 2.3s1.6 5.4 3.6 9.9 3.4 8.9 3.1 9.8c-1.1 2.7-5.9 3.7-16.9 3.3-14.9-.4-14.9-.5-9.7-13.8 2.3-5.8 4.3-11.6 4.6-13s.9-3 1.3-3.5c.4-.6 1.1-2.6 1.5-4.5.9-4.3 3.1-8 4.8-8 .8 0 2.3 3 3.5 6.7zm260.2-4.6c.7 1.1 2.2 5.5 3.5 9.7 3.2 10.5 5.3 16.2 6.9 19.2.8 1.4 1.7 4.1 2.1 6.1.6 3.4.5 3.7-2.6 4.8-3.9 1.4-20.8 1.5-24.3.1-3.1-1.2-3.3-3.4-.7-9.2 1.1-2.4 2.7-7 3.7-10.3s2.1-6.5 2.5-7c.3-.6 1.6-4.3 2.9-8.3 2.4-7.4 4.1-8.8 6-5.1z' fill='%23d87602'%3E%3C/path%3E%3C/svg%3E") no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="icon">

</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/1v6stpy4/

Comment: No...it doesn't...even in your fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/3k6x2qz0/

Comment: It happens in Chrome.

Comment: well, for me, it seems like the image becomes a little bigger when hovered, but really just a little

Comment: Not in *my* Chrome it doesn't

Comment: @CalvinNunes That's the color transtion...it's a false sight effect.

Comment: The reason of grows the image is `transition: all 2s ease;` if u remove this it's not grow.

Comment: @Paulie_D ok, but false or not, a user in a website would say it grows...

Comment: it grows for me too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a filter instead. You simply need to find the correct value to obtain the needed color.

Here is an example:

```css
.icon {
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
  transition: all 2s ease;
  background: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 16 596.1 881.4' id='logo_kamaz'%3E%3Cpath d='m177.1 21.4c-3 3-5.9 5.2-6.6 5-1.2-.5-5.5 6.9-5.5 9.5 0 1.3-2.7 5.8-4.7 7.9-.7.7-1.3 2.1-1.3 3 0 1.8-4.5 7.7-10 13.2-9.5 9.3-29.2 22.3-32.7 21.4-2.7-.7-3.6 1.9-2.3 6.4 1 3.7.2 13.2-1.1 13.2-.5 0-.9.8-.9 1.8 0 1.1-1 2.7-2.1 3.8-1.2 1-3.2 3.5-4.4 5.4-2.7 4.3-12.1 14-15.8 16.5-1.5.9-2.7 2.2-2.7 2.9 0 .6 1.9 2.7 4.2 4.7 3.9 3.4 4.2 4 4.6 9.6.5 6.8-.8 10.2-5.9 15.2-1.8 1.9-3.5 4.9-4.1 7.3-.5 2.3-1.7 21.3-2.8 42.2-1.9 38.5-2.2 40.8-6.6 51.4-.8 1.8-1.4 4.2-1.4 5.3 0 1.2-.6 3.5-1.3 5.2-7 16.4-8.8 30.5-8.9 68.7 0 34.9 3 53.7 10.4 64.6 1.3 1.9 2.7 3.4 3.1 3.4s4.9 4.2 10 9.3 12.2 11.6 15.8 14.5 7.6 7 8.7 9.1c2.6 4.6 6.9 18 7.7 24.3.5 4 1.3 5.4 5.4 9 2.6 2.4 6.8 5.6 9.2 7.3 2.4 1.6 4.6 3.2 4.9 3.5 1.1 1.2 10.1 7 10.9 7 2.6 0 12.4 12 17.5 21.5 1.5 2.7 3.5 6.2 4.4 7.6.9 1.5 2.8 4.6 4.2 6.9 2.4 4 3.9 4.9 26.7 16.2 22.5 11 29.3 15.3 29.3 18.5 0 2.2 10.5 12 15.2 14.2 6.2 2.8 14.9 2.8 20.6.1 4.5-2.2 13.8-12.6 14.8-16.6 1.2-4.7-3.2-17.4-6.1-17.4-.8 0-1.8-.6-2.2-1.4-1.5-2.6-8.5-6.5-12.9-7.2-2.4-.3-4.7-1-5-1.5s-1.4-.9-2.6-.9c-1.7 0-1.9.4-1.3 2.2.4 1.3.8 3.9.9 5.8.1 2.6-.3 3.5-1.7 3.8-4.4.9-6.7-.8-11.2-8.5-2.5-4.3-4.5-8.4-4.5-9.2 0-1.8-3.9-9.9-5.1-10.7-.5-.3-.9-1.3-.9-2.3s-.7-2.4-1.5-3.1-1.5-1.9-1.5-2.6c0-2.7-7.6-8.7-16.5-12.9-8.1-3.9-9.4-4.8-12.7-10-3.3-5-3.6-6.1-2.9-9.3.7-3.5.9-3.7 4.7-3.5 2.1.1 5.3.9 6.9 1.7 1.7.9 3.6 1.6 4.3 1.6s3.7 1.1 6.5 2.4c5.7 2.6 8.1 3.2 17.7 4.7 3.6.6 7.7 1.7 9.2 2.5 1.4.7 3.1 1.4 3.8 1.4 2 0 8.9 6.2 13.2 11.9 2.3 3.1 4.8 6.2 5.5 6.9s1.3 1.7 1.3 2.1c0 .5 3.1 2.8 7 5.2 5 3.1 8.4 6.3 12 11.1 2.7 3.7 5 6.9 5 7.2 0 1.8 9.2 13.4 12.5 15.8 7.2 5 8.4 6.5 12 14.1 1.9 4.2 3.5 7.9 3.5 8.2 0 .6 3.5 8.6 6.4 14.5 1.2 2.4 1.5 2.5 11.1 2.5 8.9-.1 10.6-.4 15.2-2.8 2.9-1.5 5.7-2.7 6.2-2.7s1.8 1.5 2.9 3.4c3.7 6.3 14.8 9.2 24.6 6.5 3.3-.9 4.1-.8 5.6.8 1.8 1.9 5.5 14.6 4.7 16-.3.4-.1 1.8.4 3 .8 2.3 1.1 2.3 17.7 2.3h16.8l5.3-5.4c3-3 6.7-6 8.3-6.7 1.9-.8 2.8-1.9 2.8-3.3 0-2.5-5.5-11.6-7-11.6-.5 0-1-.6-1-1.3-.1-.6-1.4-3-3-5.2-5.1-7-12-18.5-12-20 0-.8-.6-1.8-1.3-2.2-1.6-.9-3.7-6.6-3.7-9.9 0-1.3-.6-2.7-1.4-3.1-1.7-1-8-9.2-10-13.2-.9-1.6-3.7-6-6.2-9.6-4.4-6.3-4.7-7.2-5.5-15.8-.5-5.1-1.5-10.8-2.3-12.7-2.5-6.5-4.6-13.8-4.6-15.7 0-1.1-.7-2.8-1.5-3.9-.8-1-1.5-2.9-1.5-4.2 0-1.4-.9-2.6-2.4-3.1-2.8-1.1-7.5-7.4-11.2-15-4.1-8.4-4.3-9-5.5-17.1-2.7-19-5.5-33-6.8-34.3-.6-.6-1.1-2.3-1.1-3.7s-.7-3.5-1.5-4.6c-.8-1-1.5-2.8-1.5-4 0-1.1-.7-2.9-1.5-4-.8-1-1.5-2.9-1.5-4.2 0-2-3.5-9.8-5.1-11.2-1-1-4.9-9.1-4.9-10.3 0-.7-.5-1.8-1.1-2.4-.7-.7-1.3-6.3-1.5-14.5-.3-14.1-2.6-41-4.3-49.3-.6-2.8-1.8-9.3-2.6-14.5-1.2-6.8-2.6-11.3-5.1-15.8-2-3.8-3.4-7.7-3.4-9.8 0-3.2.4-3.7 4.6-5.6 3.4-1.5 5.9-1.9 9.3-1.5 16.9 2 23.5 2.9 30.1 4.4 5.9 1.4 12 1.8 29 1.7 19.4 0 22-.2 27-2.1 6.3-2.5 7-3.5 3.5-5.1-6.6-3 .5-9.8 13-12.5 4.4-1 9.8-2.2 12-2.8s5.6-1.4 7.5-1.9c9.6-2.4 16.7-6.6 15.7-9.4-.4-1-1.8-1.6-3.7-1.6-2.2 0-3-.5-3-1.8 0-2.4 3-5.2 5.6-5.2 1-.1 3-.7 4.4-1.5s3.7-1.4 5.2-1.5c1.5 0 2.9-.4 3.2-.9s2-1.2 3.8-1.5c3.7-.8 7.7-3.8 10.3-7.9 2.5-3.9 1-5.2-4.1-3.7-3 .9-14.1.8-46.9-.3-47-1.5-72.8-1.4-90.5.2-13.7 1.3-33.1 5.1-39.2 7.7-8.9 3.9-26.5 12.7-31 15.6-5.4 3.4-7.3 3.4-23.8.3-7.8-1.4-11.9-1.6-23-1-20 1.1-20.1 1.1-22.1-1.4-1.1-1.3-1.6-2.8-1.1-3.5.4-.6.7-15.7.7-33.6 0-40.5-.6-38.4 12.3-39.3 9.3-.7 19.9-3 21.6-4.7.5-.5 1.8-1 2.7-1s3.5-1.9 5.8-4.3c4-4.2 4.6-4.4 12.9-5.5 14.5-1.9 25.5-2.1 27.7-.6 2.4 1.8 8.9 1.8 12.3 0 3.7-1.9 6.7-5.5 8.1-9.5 2.2-6.8 2.2-6.8-8.8-6.3-14.2.7-19.3-1.4-17.2-7.1 2-5.2 3.2-5.5 23.5-7.6 8.7-.9 10.3-1.4 12.8-3.8 3.9-3.7 4-8.9.1-10.3-1.6-.6-4.1-1.7-5.7-2.6-2.1-1.2-3.9-1.4-7-.9-12.6 2.4-19.3.2-18-5.9 1.1-5.4 2.5-6.1 8.3-4.2 7.4 2.4 9.1 2.2 9.1-1.3 0-3-2-5.3-4.8-5.7-1-.1-4.6-.7-8.2-1.3-4.1-.7-16-.8-32.2-.4-23.6.6-26.7.4-36.5-1.5-6-1.1-14.8-2.6-19.8-3.2-12.5-1.6-15.5-3.9-12.1-9.3.8-1.2 1.7-3.2 2.1-4.4.5-1.9.3-2.2-1.2-1.6-1 .3-2.5 1.2-3.3 1.8-1.5 1.3-15.4 4.5-19.4 4.5-1.2 0-3-.6-4-1.3-1.5-1.1-1.6-2.1-.6-9.9 1-8 .7-11.8-.9-11.8-.4 0-3.1 2.4-6 5.4zm64.5 37.8c1.6 1.2 3.1 2.3 3.2 2.4.2.1.7 1.8 1.2 3.8.6 2.9.4 3.8-1.4 5.5-3.2 3-8.9 3.6-14.1 1.6-7.4-2.8-8.7-6.2-4.1-11.4 4.1-4.6 10.6-5.4 15.2-1.9zm-33.2 78.8c1.7 1.7 1.8 2.6.7 16.1-.7 7.9-1.6 20.2-2.2 27.4-.6 7.1-.9 25-.6 39.7.3 25.6.3 26.8-1.5 27.4-3.3 1-5.5-2.1-6.1-8.9-.6-6.4-1.8-12.2-4.5-21.6-1.2-4.4-1.5-11.4-1.4-36.5.1-46.1.6-48.5 9.4-46.4 2.3.6 5.1 1.9 6.2 2.8zm32.5 87.5c5.2.8 9.9 1.9 10.4 2.4.6.6 1.9 1.1 2.8 1.1 1 0 5.2 1.5 9.3 3.4 6.8 3.1 7.7 3.3 9.1 2 .8-.9 1.5-3.1 1.5-5 0-5.1 1.2-4.9 18 2.9 3.6 1.7 9.1 5.2 12.3 7.8 6.9 5.7 15.9 16.5 17.7 21.1.6 1.8 1.8 4.9 2.6 6.8 1.9 4.9 3.4 15.2 3.4 23.5-.1 6.2-.7 10.9-3.9 27.5-.5 2.5-1.9 7-3.1 10s-2.3 7-2.5 8.8c-.2 4.3-3.7 7.8-9.9 9.9-5.5 1.9-5.9 2-9.3 2.2-3.9.2-4.1 7.1-.2 7.1 3.2 0 8.7 2.7 11.5 5.7 8.2 8.7 11.5 18.1 7.7 21.9-2.5 2.5-7.7 4.4-11.9 4.4-3.3 0-4.4-.7-9.3-6.1-8.4-9.2-11.2-10.2-20-7.3-3.6 1.1-5.4 1.3-7.5.4-2.6-1-2.8-1.4-2.3-4.8.7-4.3 6.6-10.2 10.3-10.2 1.2 0 2.9-1.1 3.9-2.6 1.6-2.5 1.6-2.9.1-6.1-.9-1.8-1.6-3.8-1.6-4.3s-2.2-4.2-5-8.2c-2.7-4-5-7.7-5-8.3s-1.2-2.4-2.7-4.1c-1.6-1.6-3.7-4.3-4.7-5.9-2.2-3.3-4.5-6.2-20.9-25-6.2-7.2-11.7-13.7-12.2-14.5-.6-.8-1.3-4.2-1.7-7.5s-1.2-9.2-1.7-13c-1.8-12.8-3.2-31.8-2.5-33.9 1.3-4.1 3-4.3 17.3-2.1zm1.3 101.3c.7.7 1.9 1.2 2.8 1.2 4 0 15 16.2 15 22 0 3.4-1.9 9-3.1 9-.5 0-.9.9-.9 2.1 0 2.9-4.6 8.5-9 11-3.4 1.9-3.9 2.7-5 8.3-1.3 6.8-2.8 9-8.2 11.7-6.7 3.4-15.8 1.8-15.8-2.8 0-4.5 2.8-9.8 7.3-13.5 2.6-2.2 4.7-4.6 4.7-5.4s.5-2.3 1.2-3.3c.9-1.5.7-2.5-1.1-5.5-1.3-2-2.8-3.5-3.4-3.4-.7.1-4.7-2.3-8.9-5.5-6.2-4.6-7.9-6.4-8.7-9.5-1.9-6.7-1.4-11.7 1.6-15.2l2.7-3.2 13.8.4c8.7.3 14.3.9 15 1.6zm-99.9 31.1c8.3 5.6 23.6 19.6 25.6 23.5 2.1 3.8 6.7 6.3 13.1 6.9 6 .5 15.7 3.4 16.6 4.8.3.5 2.4.9 4.8.9 5.6 0 7.9 2.4 7.4 7.6-.3 3.5-.8 4.1-6.2 7.2-7.4 4.3-12.2 4.9-23.4 2.9-4.8-.9-13.5-2-19.4-2.5-9.5-.8-11.5-1.3-19.5-5.1-18.1-8.7-21.4-13.4-22.9-32.8-.6-7-.5-7.3 2.2-9.9 2.9-2.6 12.2-8.4 13.7-8.4.4 0 4 2.2 8 4.9zm195.6 55.9c7.8 5.1 10.9 10.2 16.2 27.2 1.1 3.6 2.7 7.8 3.6 9.5.8 1.6 3.6 7 6.1 12 2.6 4.9 6.5 12.3 8.9 16.3s4.3 7.6 4.3 8 2 3.7 4.4 7.3c3.5 5.5 4.4 7.7 4.9 12.8.5 5.7.3 6.3-1.9 7.7-4.9 3.3-13.8 1.5-17-3.4-1.5-2.2-1.7-4.8-1.7-14.5.2-11.5.1-11.8-2.5-14.4-1.5-1.5-3.1-3.5-3.7-4.4-5.8-10-8.3-13.4-13.7-18.6-3.5-3.3-8.3-7-10.6-8.2-8-4.1-17.3-22.7-15.9-31.7.3-2 1.3-4.7 2.3-6.1 1.5-2.4 1.9-2.5 7.6-1.9 3.4.4 7.2 1.5 8.7 2.4zm-42.9 16.4c5.7 10.8 11.7 18.2 18 22.1 6.9 4.1 12.2 8.6 15.7 13.3 3.9 5.1 11.4 22.2 13.9 31.9 2.4 9.3 8.5 21.1 14.5 28.1 1.5 1.8 3.5 5.4 4.5 8 1 2.7 2.4 6 3.1 7.4 1.6 3.1 1.7 7.2.1 8.8-2.4 2.4-6.2 1.1-17.7-5.8-15.2-9.2-15.1-9.2-16.2-14.1-1-4.4-6.1-10.1-18.2-20.4-5.9-4.9-9.7-10.6-9.7-14.4 0-1-.6-2.1-1.4-2.4-.7-.3-1.7-1.8-2.1-3.4-.3-1.5-1-3-1.4-3.3s-2-3-3.4-6.2c-2.9-6-8.7-11.7-18.7-18.1-3-1.9-6.8-4.8-8.4-6.5-2.5-2.7-2.7-3.5-2.1-7.4.4-2.3 1.6-6 2.7-8.1 2.6-5.1 9.6-12.7 11.7-12.7 1 0 2.6-.7 3.7-1.5 1-.8 3.3-1.5 5-1.5 2.9 0 3.5.6 6.4 6.2zm-130.6 9.7c4.8 4 11.6 16.5 14.7 26.9.6 1.9 2.1 5.4 3.5 7.9 1.3 2.5 2.4 4.9 2.4 5.3 0 2.6 8 12.3 13 16 8.8 6.3 9.2 12.8.9 15-6.5 1.8-10.1 1-11.9-2.5-.9-1.7-2.8-4.9-4.3-7.2-1.5-2.4-2.7-4.5-2.7-4.8s-1-2-2.2-3.8c-8.6-12.3-12.6-17.1-16.2-19.6-2.2-1.6-6.5-5.2-9.3-7.9-5.3-5-5.3-5.1-5.3-11.2 0-11.5 4.8-17.5 13-16.2 1.4.3 3.4 1.2 4.4 2.1zm228.8 101.3c3.8 3.1 17.3 28.3 18.3 34.1.5 3.4.2 4.2-2.8 7.2-2.7 2.7-4.3 3.5-7.1 3.5-4.3 0-5.5-1.9-5.5-8.1 0-2.4-.5-9-1.2-14.5l-1.2-10.1h-4c-5.3 0-8.5-3.4-6.4-6.7.8-1.2 1.9-3.1 2.6-4.4 1.3-2.4 4.8-2.9 7.3-1zm-393.2 142.3v11.5l297.8-.2 297.7-.3.3-9.5c.3-11.4-.2-12.3-4.8-11-2.3.7-105.5 1-293.1 1-255.2 0-290.1-.2-293.2-1.5-2-.8-3.9-1.5-4.2-1.5s-.5 5.2-.5 11.5zm126.2 75.1c-2.1.9-6.8 1.5-13 1.5-17.1.1-14.9-1.2-39.2 23.3-11.8 11.9-22.5 21.9-23.7 22.2s-3.1.3-4.3-.1c-1.9-.6-2.1-1.2-1.5-4.3.4-2.1.9-12 1.2-22.3l.4-18.5-17.8-.2c-9.8-.1-19-.4-20.4-.8-2.1-.4-2.8-.1-3.3 1.8-.3 1.3-.6 32.3-.6 69v66.8h42.5l-.3-27-.4-26.9 5.3-5.6c2.8-3 5.7-5.5 6.4-5.5 1.8 0 4 3 6.4 9 1.2 3 2.6 6.4 3.1 7.5s2.3 5.8 4 10.5c1.8 4.7 4 10.3 5 12.5s3 7.6 4.5 12 3.5 9.2 4.3 10.7l1.6 2.8 27.1.1c14.8.1 27.7 0 28.5-.1 2-.3 2.9-1.8 3.6-6.3.4-2.1 1.5-4.9 2.6-6.2l1.9-2.5h19.9c10.9 0 20.6.3 21.5.6 1.7.7 4.3 5.9 5.4 10.9l.7 3h59.6l-.1-35.2c-.1-19.8.2-35.4.7-35.7 1-.6 5.2 4.7 5.2 6.6 0 1.6 4.5 14.7 5.4 15.5.3.4.6 1.7.6 3s.6 3.6 1.4 5.1 1.8 4.6 2.1 6.7c.4 2.2 1 4.4 1.4 5 1.2 2 6.3 17.1 7.1 21.3 1.1 5.1 2.5 7.8 4.2 8.3.7.2 8.5.2 17.3-.1l15.9-.5 1.8-5c1.8-4.8 2.2-6.3 4.8-16.5.7-2.5 1.8-5.9 2.6-7.7.8-1.7 1.4-3.7 1.4-4.5 0-.7 2.1-7.4 4.5-14.8 2.5-7.4 4.5-14.7 4.5-16.1 0-2.7 3.5-6.8 4.7-5.5.4.4.6 16.4.4 35.7l-.3 34.9h31.6c24.5 0 31.7-.3 32-1.3 4.1-14.5 2.5-13.7 27-13.7h20.4l2 3.4c1.1 1.8 2.3 4.8 2.7 6.5s1.6 3.7 2.8 4.4c1.7.9 17.1 1.1 66.7.7l64.5-.5.3-7.1c.3-7.9-1.1-13.5-3-11.6-.8.8-7.5 1.2-21.8 1.2-17 0-20.9-.3-22.8-1.6-2.7-1.9-2.8-3.8-.3-7.2 1-1.5 2.9-5.2 4.1-8.2s3.4-8 4.7-11c1.4-3 3.4-8 4.5-11 1.9-5.3 3.5-9.3 6.3-15.5.7-1.7 2.1-5 3-7.5 2.4-6.3 3.8-9.5 7.4-17.1 1.7-3.6 3.1-7.3 3.1-8.3s.6-3 1.4-4.4c.8-1.5 2.2-4.5 3.1-6.7s2.2-5.4 3-7c4.7-10.7 5.8-13.6 5.3-14-.3-.3-4.1-.2-8.4.2-7.6.8-80.8.1-84.9-.8-1.9-.4-2 .2-2.3 9.2-.3 11.6-2.4 10.6 21.5 10.7 12.2.1 16.9.5 17.5 1.4 1 1.6.3 6.2-1.6 10.3-.8 1.6-1.9 4.1-2.4 5.5-.6 1.4-2.2 5.1-3.6 8.2s-2.6 5.9-2.6 6.2-1.7 4.3-3.9 8.8c-2.1 4.6-4.2 9.8-4.5 11.5-.4 1.8-1.2 3.5-1.7 3.8-.5.4-.9 1.4-.9 2.4s-.7 2.4-1.5 3.1-1.5 2-1.5 2.9-1.6 4.7-3.5 8.6c-1.9 3.8-3.5 7.8-3.5 8.7s-.4 1.9-.9 2.2c-.4.3-1.1 2.6-1.5 5.2-.7 5.5-2 7.4-5.1 7.4-3.2 0-4.1-1.6-5.4-8.9-.6-3.6-1.5-6.9-2.1-7.5-.5-.5-1-2.4-1-4.2 0-1.7-.7-3.7-1.5-4.4s-1.5-2.3-1.5-3.5c0-1.3-.7-3.6-1.5-5.1-.8-1.6-1.5-4.3-1.5-6.1 0-1.7-.7-3.8-1.5-4.6-.7-.8-1.7-2.6-2.1-4.1-.3-1.4-1-2.9-1.5-3.2s-.9-1.8-.9-3.3-.7-3.6-1.5-4.7c-.8-1-1.5-3.4-1.5-5.2s-.5-4.3-1.2-5.5c-1.9-3.4-4.7-12-4.8-14.3 0-1.2-.7-2.7-1.5-3.4s-1.5-2-1.5-3-.7-3.4-1.5-5.3c-.8-2-1.5-4.9-1.5-6.4-.1-1.5-1.1-4.6-2.4-6.8-2.8-4.8-4.6-5.3-21.4-5.6l-12.3-.1-2 3.6c-1 2-1.9 4.8-1.9 6.3 0 1.6-.7 4.1-1.5 5.7-.8 1.5-1.5 3.5-1.5 4.3s-.6 2.7-1.4 4.1c-.7 1.5-2.4 6.1-3.7 10.2-1.2 4.1-2.9 8.6-3.6 10s-1.3 3.5-1.3 4.8c0 1.2-.4 3-.9 4-.5.9-1.7 3.7-2.6 6.2s-2.3 6-3.1 7.8-1.4 4.4-1.4 5.7c0 2.3-1.6 6.7-4.6 12.8-.8 1.6-1.4 3.8-1.4 5s-.9 4.9-1.9 8.2c-1.4 4.5-2.4 6.1-3.9 6.3-2.6.4-4.9-3.3-3.3-5.2.8-.9 1-16.5.9-50.7-.3-41.3-.5-49.4-1.7-49.1-.7.2-11.6.3-24.1.4l-22.7.1-1.3 3.1c-.7 1.7-1.7 4.2-2.1 5.6s-2.4 7-4.4 12.5-4.3 12.4-5.1 15.3c-.7 2.8-2.1 6.9-3 9-2.8 6.8-5.1 14.6-6.4 21.7-1.5 8.8-4.6 11.7-8.4 7.9-1-1-1.6-3.3-1.6-6.4 0-2.6-.7-6.1-1.5-7.6-.8-1.6-1.5-4.3-1.5-5.9 0-1.7-.7-3.9-1.5-4.9-.8-1.1-1.5-2.8-1.5-3.9 0-1-.6-3.1-1.4-4.5-1.3-2.6-3.1-8.8-4.6-16.2-.3-1.9-1.4-5-2.4-6.8-1-1.9-1.5-3.6-1.2-3.9s0-1.5-.7-2.7c-.6-1.1-1.3-3.2-1.4-4.6-.1-1.3-1.1-3.6-2.1-5l-1.9-2.5-22.8-.2c-14.3-.2-23.2-.7-24-1.3-1-.8-1.6-.7-2.2.2-1.3 2.1-1.6 77.7-.3 91.7 1.1 10.7 1 12.5-.3 13.8-3.2 3.3-7.7-2.7-7.7-10.3 0-1.8-.4-3.6-1-3.9-.5-.3-1-1.5-1-2.7 0-1.1-.6-3.2-1.4-4.6-.8-1.5-2.2-5.9-3.1-9.7-1-3.9-2.3-7.7-3-8.5s-1.5-2.6-1.8-4-1-4-1.6-5.8c-2.6-7.7-3.3-9.9-4.1-12.7-1.3-4.8-3.1-9.8-4.6-12.8-.8-1.6-1.4-3.6-1.4-4.6 0-.9-.7-2.6-1.5-3.7-.8-1-1.5-2.8-1.5-3.8 0-4.2-4.1-15.4-5.8-16.1-.9-.4-6-.9-11.2-1.1-5.2-.3-11.8-.6-14.6-.7-4.8-.3-5.2-.2-6.7 2.7-.9 1.7-1.9 4.4-2.3 6.1-.8 3.8-3.2 11.4-4.4 14-.4 1.1-1.8 4.9-3 8.5-1.1 3.6-2.4 7.4-2.9 8.5-1.8 4.1-3 8.1-3.7 12-.3 2.2-1.2 5-2 6.2s-1.4 3.1-1.4 4.1-.7 2.7-1.5 3.8c-.8 1-1.5 2.6-1.5 3.5 0 1.7-2.2 8.7-6.5 20.4-1.3 3.8-2.8 9.2-3.1 12-.9 6.9-1.9 8.5-5.4 8.5-3.3 0-4.4-1.5-5.5-7.4-.3-2.2-1.3-4.9-2.1-6s-1.4-3-1.4-4.3c0-1.8-1.1-4.5-7.1-16.5-.5-1-.9-2.6-.9-3.6s-.7-2.7-1.5-3.8c-.8-1-1.5-2.8-1.5-3.9s-.9-3.8-2-6-1.9-4.4-2-4.8c0-.5-.7-1.5-1.5-2.3-.8-.9-1.5-2.4-1.5-3.4s-.4-2.2-1-2.5c-.5-.3-1-2.5-1-4.8 0-4.1.3-4.5 19-22.7 20.9-20.4 23.2-23.8 13.2-19.4zm48.6 68.1c1.2 3.8 2.2 7.6 2.2 8.5s.5 2 1 2.3c.6.3 1 1.4 1 2.3s1.6 5.4 3.6 9.9 3.4 8.9 3.1 9.8c-1.1 2.7-5.9 3.7-16.9 3.3-14.9-.4-14.9-.5-9.7-13.8 2.3-5.8 4.3-11.6 4.6-13s.9-3 1.3-3.5c.4-.6 1.1-2.6 1.5-4.5.9-4.3 3.1-8 4.8-8 .8 0 2.3 3 3.5 6.7zm260.2-4.6c.7 1.1 2.2 5.5 3.5 9.7 3.2 10.5 5.3 16.2 6.9 19.2.8 1.4 1.7 4.1 2.1 6.1.6 3.4.5 3.7-2.6 4.8-3.9 1.4-20.8 1.5-24.3.1-3.1-1.2-3.3-3.4-.7-9.2 1.1-2.4 2.7-7 3.7-10.3s2.1-6.5 2.5-7c.3-.6 1.6-4.3 2.9-8.3 2.4-7.4 4.1-8.8 6-5.1z' fill='%230d53a0'%3E%3C/path%3E%3C/svg%3E") no-repeat;
}


.icon:hover {
  filter:hue-rotate(181deg) brightness(168%)  
}
```

```html
<div class="icon">

</div>
```